# Why does static qualifier on a file scope POD change a Valgrind finding?

Tags: c++, static, initialization, valgrind

I'm working on a project that uses a few file scope variables. They are `bool` and `unsigned int`, they are initialized to `false` and a scalar, and they reside in an `*.cpp` files:

```
/* CPP implementation file */
bool g_b1 = false, bool g_b2 = false;
unsigned int g_n1 = 32;
```

Without the `static` qualifier Valgrind will produce a finding:

> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

With the `static` qualifier, the finding is not present.

As I understand POD initialization, both `non-static` (0-initialized) and `static` PODs go in the `BSS`, so they are all effectively initialized. But in this case, they are explicitly initialized, so splitting hairs about what is initialized should be a moot point. Also see Wikipedia's [.bss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) for a treatment of the BSS.

Finally, we are not using flags like `-fno-zero-initialized-in-bss`. The flags and options are conservative: `-DNDEBUG -g3 -O1 -march=native`. `-O1` is used because [Valgrind requires it for accurate results](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html).

Since Valgrind is producing different results, something is likely changing with and without the use of `static`. I'm trying to understand what changes and the interactions of the changes (and not how to "solve this problem").

Why is Valgrind producing a finding without the `static` qualifier?

---

The actual source file can be foumd at [cpu.cpp](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/cpu_8cpp_source.html#l00140), lines 145, 146 and 147.

Comment: Your code seems to be C++ and not C, or perhaps you are compiling C code as C++? In any case, both language differ, in particular on their initialization strategies. (And POD also is C++ jargon and not C.)

Comment: Thanks Jens. That's been corrected. I try to avoid the C++ tag because some of the folks who patrol it are intolerable. I try to stay away from them. I wish they would reciprocate.

Comment: Care for a minimal example as per SO guidelines? My guess is you are using these globals in during initialization of other globals (a.k.a. static initialization order fiasco).

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - Correct me if I am wrong, but BSS initialization occurs before any constructors run. That is, the memory backing the variables are 0-iniialized when the page for it is mapped into memory. And sorry, I don't have a minimal example. I don't know how to provide a minimal example that tests mapping pages by the link-loader and the way it interacts with Valgrind. That's why I have to ask about the interactions.

Comment: You can make a simplified testcase program as a c file. Then you may change the tag back to c

Comment: @Johannes - forgive my ignorance, but how, exactly, do I write a test program that tests how the compiler, link-loader and Valgrind interact for static and 0-value initialized allocations? I think you and Ulrich are missing the point of the question. I'm not trying to solve the Valgrind finding - I already know the answer to that - add `static`. Now I'm trying to understand why it solves it.

Comment: Having a look into your source, it really seems that your function is called from another TU before the C++ initialization code is called. This is what Ulrich refers to as "static initialization order fiasco". Another way to avoid that problem (which is in fact a real problem of C++ as a language) by not initializing the variables explicitly. `false` is the default initialization anyhow, so maybe the compiler manages better. Another idea would be to have all these variables as `extern` and implement them in a C TU.

Comment: @Jens - thanks, that's interesting (and troubling to me). I thought these 0-initialized got their initial value when the link loader maps in the BSS. If that's not the case, then there's a deferred intialization going on, and I do in fact have to worry about *static initialization order fiasco* for these PODs. I'm actually well aware of the problem, and I asked this question because of [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Static_Initialization_Order_Fiasco). Apparently, there are some details that I don't understand.